# Existence of a singleton set consisting of the union of itself

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC, can it be shown whether or not there exists a set $x$ (other than $1=\{\emptyset\}$) such that

$$
 x = \{\cup x\}?
$$

Comment: Try $x=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow that got by me.

Answer (score 5):

Every singleton has this property: if $x=\{a\}$ then $\bigcup x=\bigcup\{a\}=a$ so that $\{\bigcup x\}=\{a\}=x$.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed this. So simple.